# Existe a possibilidade de retornar os valores de um ResultSet?

Tags: java

Seguinte, eu gostaria de: se o livro já estiver como "emprestado" no banco, exibir pra quem foi emprestado, e se nao estiver, permitir o emprestimo. Com isso, se ja existisse esse emprestimo, gostaria de retornar essas informações para a Control (quem chamou) e exibir la, pois se eu tento exibir na DAO ANTES de fechar o resultSet, dá o erro:

```
java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set
```

E se eu tento exibir DEPOIS de fechar o resultSet, não é possivel, ja que foi fechado.

Existe a possibilidade de salvar essas informações (nome, data de emprestimo, responsavel) numa lista ou algo do tipo, e retornar para o metodo que chamou?

Método na CONTROL que chama a DAO:

```
    public void RealizaEmprestimo (String tituloLivro, String isbn, Date dataE,
                               String horaE, Date dataD, String horaD,
                               double multa, String funcionario, String responsavel,
                               String tipoResponsavel) 
                               throws SQLException {

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dataFormatadaE = formatter.format(dataE);
String dataFormatadaD = formatter.format(dataD);

Emprestimo emprestimo = new Emprestimo (dataFormatadaE, horaE, dataFormatadaD, horaD,
                                        multa, funcionario, responsavel,tituloLivro, 
                                        isbn, tipoResponsavel);


if(ed.checkEmprestimo(emprestimo)){
    **Aqui é onde seria exibida as informações retornadas da DAO**

    }
else {
    ed.insert(emprestimo);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Emprestimo realizado com sucesso!");
}

}
```

Metodo DAO:

```
    public boolean checkEmprestimo (Emprestimo emprestimo) throws SQLException {

    PreparedStatement stmt= c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM emprestimo WHERE isbn = ? ");

    stmt.setString(1, emprestimo.getIsbn());


    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    boolean hasEmprestimo = rs.next();

    if (!rs.next()) {
    String tipoResponsavel = rs.getString("tipoResponsavel");
    String responsavel = rs.getString("responsavel");
    String dataEmprestimo = rs.getString("dataEmprestimo");
    String horaE = rs.getString("horaE");
    String dataDevolucao = rs.getString("dataDevolucao");
    String horaD = rs.getString("horaD");

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Emprestado para o " + tipoResponsavel + " " +
                responsavel + " no dia " + dataEmprestimo + " às " +horaE + "\n\n" +
                "Entrega prevista para " + dataDevolucao + (" às ") + horaD);             
    }


    stmt.close();
    rs.close();
    return hasEmprestimo;
}
```

PS: se eu tiro do IF, ele funciona SE tiver o emprestimo no banco, mas se nao tiver, ele dá erro na hora de atribuir esses valores para as variáveis.

E tambem nao gostaria de tratar esse if e else no DAO, pois no padrao MVC quem cuida da logica é a controller.

Comment: Se ficou dificil de entender, eu gostaria que SE tivesse o emprestimo no banco, que fosse retornado para a CONTROLLER para ser exibido la (as informações), e deixar a DAO somente com a função de pesquisar no banco.

Comment: Os topicos indicados nao dão certo, foi por isso que lancei esse novo. Poderiam informar o motivo antes de dar negativo e a dúvida persistir.

Comment: `if (!rs.next())` quer dizer que vai entrar no `if` se não houver mais nenhuma informação no `ResultSet` (veja a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next())). E quando você tenta usar `getString` em um `ResultSet` que não tem mais nenhum dado, ocorre o erro "After end of result set". O certo é fazer `if (rs.next())`, ou, no seu caso, fazer `if (hasEmprestimo)` (chamar `next()` de novo vai mover o `ResultSet` para o próximo registro, então vc não deve chamar várias vezes se for para verificar apenas um resultado).

Answer (score 1):

O ideal, nesses métodos de busca, não é retornar `boolean`, mas a própria entidade (ou objeto) que você está buscando na base. Isso porque, como você mesmo percebeu, retornar um `boolean` nesse caso tem pouca utilidade para a sequência que seu programa precisa. Não seria muito melhor fazer uma busca e, encontrando, retornar um `Livro` ou, não encontrando, retornar `null` ou mesmo um `Livro` vazio, por exemplo? Você consegue o mesmo efeito de confirmação que o `boolean` te dá, mas com a vantagem de ter o objeto disponível para trabalhar caso ele exista.

Assim, em vez de seu método retornar um `boolean`, retornaria um objeto criado por você e que conteria os dados recuperados no `ResultSet`. Por exemplo, uma classe `Livro`:

```
class Livro {
  private String tipoResponsavel;
  private String responsavel;
  ...
  //Construtores e getters/setters
}
```

Haverá uma pequena alteração no seu método DAO. Você, em vez de setar `hasEmprestimo` de acordo com a busca, vai alimentar o objeto `Livro` para retorná-lo mais tarde:

```
ResultSet ...

Livro livro;
if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
    livro = new Livro();
    livro.setTipoResponsavel = rs.getString("tipoResponsavel");
    ... //setar as outras propriedades
}

return livro;
```

Agora, sempre um `Livro` será retornado. Se houver dados na base, um preenchido; se não houver, um livro nulo.

A assinatura do seu método, então, passaria a ser assim:

```
public Livro checkEmprestimo (Emprestimo emprestimo) throws SQLException {
```

No *controller*, sua lógica se alteraria também:

```
Emprestimo emprestimo ...

Livro livroPesquisado = ed.checkEmprestimo(emprestimo); //livro preenchido ou nulo

if(livroPesquisado != null) {
  //sua lógica aqui, acessando o objeto livroPesquisado e fazendo o que quiser
} else {
...
}
```

Dessa forma, você tem seu objeto e pode trabalhar com ele de maneira fácil e descomplicada.

Por fim, uma observação arquitetural/design. Sua classe DAO não deve ser responsável por nada que não seja a consulta à base de dados. Exibir lá uma mensagem para o usuário, como você faz hoje, deveria ser responsabilidade de uma classe de serviço, que recebe os dados da sua View (a interface com o usuário) e se conecta com o DAO, ou da própria classe de Controller.

Outra coisa são métodos/construtores com muito parâmetros. São altamente não recomendados devido à dificuldade de manutenção e de legibilidade. Pesquise sobre um *design pattern* chamado `Builder`.